# Need Generic Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, generics

I want to make generic constructor for the following code.

As the different enum will be added in following scenario . I want that class to be generic.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using TT.SharedServices.Utils;

namespace TT.Core
{
[DataContract(Namespace = "SharedServices")]
public class Error
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Error Code
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets detailed error message
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }


    public Error()
    {
        ErrorMessage = NullValues.NullString;
        ErrorCode = NullValues.NullInt;
    }

    public Error(AuthenticateErrorType errorType, string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorCode = (int) errorType;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public Error(LoadMemberErrorType errorType, string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorCode = (int)errorType;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
 }
}
```

Suggest me best optimized way to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Since it is a DataContract, generics are not supported  as nicely as you would assume. You could perhaps Change errorType to int before Calling the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non-generic code such as

```
public Error(Enum errorType, string errorMessage)
{
    ErrorCode = (int)(object)errorType;
    ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
}
```

Generis would not help that much anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can think of creating a generic factory method to create instanced instead of constructor:

```
public static Error CreateError<T>(T errorType, string errorMessage)
{
    // Add if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw ... here if you wish
    return new Error()
    {
        ErrorCode = (int)(object)errorType,
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage
    };
}
```

Hopefully, in future version of C# it will be easier, as mentioned in point *8. Constructor type parameter inference* in article [Probable C# 6.0 features illustrated](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated).

Comment: deleted my post in favour of this one.

Comment: Interesting list of features there; the feature there that's closest to one I'd like to see would be a means of having constructor parameters participate in field or property initialization.  Allowing that in general (as opposed to requiring that the entire class be of a certain form) would avoid the need to have field declaration and initialization located at different places in the source, and also allow fields whose initialization depends upon constructor parameters to be initialized before calling the base constructor.  Any idea if any such things are discussed anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

User following code:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "SharedServices")]
public class Error<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Error Code
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets detailed error message
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }


    public Error()
    {
        ErrorMessage = NullValues.NullString;
        ErrorCode = NullValues.NullInt;
    }

    public Error(T errorType, string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorCode = Convert.ToInt32(errorType);
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

}
```